# Count other non-empty cells in a row/column?

Tags: count, google-sheets

What is the simplest way of counting all non-empty cells in a given row/column **except** for one cell in that range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I came up with is counting all cells and then subtracting the one cell:

`=countif($B$3:$B$14;"<>")-countif($B3;"<>")`

Anyone's got anything better? Is it possible to do it with one function?